# Difference between two datasets with Dask and Xarray

Tags: dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I need to compute a difference between two datasets (two daily variables resampled on monthly basis) with Dask and Xarray. Here my code:

```
def diff(path_1,path_2):
    import xarray as xr
    max_v=xr.open_mfdataset(path_1, combine='by_coords', concat_dim="time", parallel=True)['variable_1'].resample({'time': '1M'}).max()
    min_v=xr.open_mfdataset(path_2, combine='by_coords', concat_dim="time", parallel=True)['variable_2'].resample({'time': '1M'}).min()
    
    return (max_v-min_v).compute()
        
future = client.submit(diff,path_1,path_2)
diff = client.gather(future)
```

I also tried this:

```
%%time
def max_var(path):
    import xarray as xr
    multi_file_dataset = xr.open_mfdataset(path, combine='by_coords', concat_dim="time", parallel=True)
    max_v=multi_file_dataset['variable_1'].resample(time='1M').max(dim='time')
    return max_v.compute()

def min_var(path):
    import xarray as xr
    multi_file_dataset = xr.open_mfdataset(path, combine='by_coords', concat_dim="time", parallel=True)
    min_v=multi_file_dataset['variable_2'].resample(time='1M').min(dim='time')
    return min_v.compute()

futures=[]
future = client.submit(max_temp,path1)
futures.append(future)
future = client.submit(min_temp,path2)
futures.append(future)
results = client.gather(futures)

diff = results[0]-results[1]
```

But I noticed that the computation becomes very slow in the final step of getitem-nanmax e getitem-nanmin (1974 out of 1980 for example).

Here the cluster configuration:

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(walltime='1:00:00',cores=5,memory='5GB')
cluster.scale(jobs=10)
```

Each datasets consists of several files: total size=7GB

Is there a better way to implement this computation?

Thanks

Comment: Minor point, but it's not a good idea to use the same name for a variable and a function, so in your first snippet consider distinguishing `diff` var/function.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Thanks for suggestion. Apart that, do you think the implementation is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure this works on your case, but without a `mwe` it's difficult to do much better. So, my suspicion is that `.compute()` used by `xarray` might conflict with the `client.submit`, because now computing is happening on the worker and I'm not sure if it can correctly distribute the work among peers (but this is a suspicion, I'm not sure). So one way out of this is to get the computations out into the main script (since `xarray` will integrate with `dask` in the backgroun), so perhaps this will work:

```py
import xarray as xr

max_v=xr.open_mfdataset(path_1, combine='by_coords', concat_dim="time", parallel=True, chunks={'time': 10})['variable_1'].resample({'time': '1M'}).max()
min_v=xr.open_mfdataset(path_2, combine='by_coords', concat_dim="time", parallel=True, chunks={'time': 10})['variable_2'].resample({'time': '1M'}).min()
    
diff_result = (max_v-min_v).compute()
```

Below is the `mwe` on a different dataset:

```py
import xarray as xr

# chunks option will create dask array
ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('rasm', decode_times=True, chunks={'time': 10})

# these are lazy calculations
max_v = ds['Tair'].resample({'time': '1M'}).max()
min_v = ds['Tair'].resample({'time': '1M'}).min()

# this will use dask scheduler in the background
diff_result = (max_v-min_v).compute()

# since the data refers to the same variable, all the results will be either 0 or `nan` (if the variable was not available in that time/x/y combination)
```

Comment: I tried the first code snippet (since I have two distinct variables), but it seems not working properly....

Comment: Did you add the `chunks` option? What is the error that you see?

Comment: Yes, I added that option. Computation is taking too much time and actually I don's see any computation from the Monitoring UI

Comment: Hmm, I didn't add it in the snippet, but you have to start the cluster. Did you do that? It's difficult to debug a problem without having a `mwe`. Can you use my `mwe` as a starting point and reproduce your problem?